# How to modify the syntax of data serie?

Tags: python, pandas, colors, series

I have a .csv file which contains datas I want to analyse. Its shape is [61 rows x 2 columns], here is what it looks like :

```
Wavelength,Intensity
400.0,38.000
405.0,40.000
410.0,46.000
415.0,56.000
...
700.0,52.000
```

I want to process this data file with the Colour library but the syntax requirements for the starting data sample in this library is :

```
data_sample = {
    400: 38.000,
    405: 40.000,
    410: 46.000,
    415: 56.000,
    ...
    700: 52.000,}
```

So I need to modify data syntax of the .csv file. The .csv data is `dtype: object` (each columns is `float64`) and the data_sample is a `dict` type (I think). So I guess the "type" has to be changed right ?

I have no idea how to change the syntax, I guess it is possible with Pandas, which would be great because the Colour Library allows to call a data sample from Pandas Series.

Do you have any idea to provide me so I can do what I want ? Any kind of suggestion/advice/help is welcomed. Thank you all ! (I am quite a rookie in python so sorry if it is not really well explained.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `Wavelength` to integers and then 2 columns to `dict` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with select column `Intensity` for `Series` and then [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df['Wavelength'] = df['Wavelength'].astype(int)

d = df.set_index('Wavelength')['Intensity'].to_dict()
```

Or you can convert index from `Wavelength` to integers:

```
d = df.set_index('Wavelength')['Intensity'].rename(index=int).to_dict()
```